# Data Type for multiple decimal points in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I have a value that would be similar to this 0000006860.18.03 when formatting the table for sql server would I use decimal or numeric?  If so could someone point me to an example.  The format would always be 10 numbers, a decimal point, 2 numbers, a decimal point and 2 numbers

Comment: Numbers don't have multiple decimal points. If you have multiple you don't have a number, you have a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have leading zeros and/or multiple separators, you need to store that as CHAR(16).  If each of the "numbers" between the separators have distinct meanings, then you have three columns, not one.

Comment: I think this is the best solution for my problem.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best option is to include them between brackets as a nvarchar.
Can't be numeric when you have zeros as a start. They will automatically be deleted.
Each time you can easily convert it with try_convert

```
select TRY_CONVERT(int,'555')
```

Comment: But `TRY_CONVERT(int,'0000006860.18.03')` is going to return `NULL`, as will `TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18,4),'0000006860.18.03')`